# Taylor series of $\frac{4x-5}{2x^2-4x+5}$ about $x = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Taylor series of the following expression about $x = 1$:

\begin{align}
\frac{4x-5}{2x^2-4x+5}
\end{align}
My steps are as follows:

\begin{align}
2x^2-4x+5 = 2(x-1)^2+3 \quad (\text{by completing the square})
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\therefore \quad\frac{4x-5}{2x^2-4x+5}
&= \frac{4x-5}{2(x-1)^2+3} \\ \\
&= \frac{4(x-1)-1}{2(x-1)^2+3} \\ \\
&= \frac{4(x-1)-1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{3}(x-1)^2} \\ \\
&= \frac{4(x-1)-1}{3}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{2^n}{3^{n}}(x-1)^{2n}\right) \\ \\
&= (4(x-1)-1)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}(x-1)^{2n}\right) \\ \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{2^{n+2}}{3^{n+1}}(x-1)^{2n+1}\right) -
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{2^{n}}{3^{n+1}}(x-1)^{2n}\right)
\end{align}

I am pretty sure my answer is wrong even though I think that my steps are correct. I am thinking that the Taylor series should turn out as a single summation term. But I can't see how to simplify this any further. Is anyone able to advise whether my method and answer is correct?

Comment: You have a problem with your index $i$ that is not present in the terms of the summation. Moreover, your series doesn't stop at $n$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah. That's right! I just double checked the definition of taylor series in my notes. Indeed, this is a major flaw in my working.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have tweaked my working a little so that the summation definition is now correct. But I will still be stuck with 2 summation terms.

Comment: You can group them under a single summation sign: you surely have noticed that you have **odd** exponents in the first summation and **even** exponents in the other. Thus you can write your answer under the following form $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}a_N(x-1)^{N}$ with $a_N =- (-1)^n \dfrac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$ if $N=2n$ (even case) and $a_N = ...$ if $N=2n+1$ (odd case).

Comment: @JeanMarie Is it correct to express the Taylor series as two summation terms as I have derived?

Comment: It is not uncorrect, but the usual presentation is with a single $\sum$.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x)=\frac{4x-5}{2x^2-4x+5}$$

and

$$g(x)=f(x+1)$$.

we expand $g(x)$ arround $x=0$.

$$g(x)=\frac{4x-1}{2x^2+3}$$

$$=\frac{4x-1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{3}x^2}$$

$$=\frac{4x-1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-\frac{2x^2}{3})^n$$.

finally

$f(x)=g(x-1)$.

Comment: I don't see a fundamental difference from the OP's formulation...

Comment: I will not polemicate. IMHOP, it is strictly speaking the same steps.